# How do you conditionally add a file to sources in boost.build?

Tags: boost, conditional-statements, bjam, boost-build, b2

build.jam:

```
project : usage-requirements <include>. ;

alias PUB : : : : <use>/ProjectA//PUB
                  <use>/ProjectB//PUB ;

lib LIB : [ glob *.c : feature.c ]
        : <link>static
          <use>/ProjectA//PUB
          <use>/ProjectB//PUB ;
```

I would like to add a target that will add feature.c to the sources and define USE_FEATURE.  I've tried a few different things, but none seem to work as I want.

```
alias LIB_WITH_FEAT : LIB feature.c : <define>USE_FEATURE ;

alias LIB_WITH_FEAT : LIB : <source>feature.c <define>USE_FEATURE ;
```

does not add feature.c or USE_FEATURE to the build.  But gives no errors or warnings.  It just builds LIB.

```
lib LIB_WITH_FEAT : feature.c LIB : <define>USE_FEATURE ;
```

gives "warn: Unable to construct LIB_WITH_FEAT".  Although if it worked, I don't think it'd be what I wanted as it would try to build LIB separately and LIB needs the USE_FEATURE to work properly with feature.c.

Comment: Your question is terribly unclear.. What do you want to add feature.c to?

Comment: Sorry, You can build target LIB to build the library, but from some projects I want to build the library with Feature X.  The implementation of Feature X is in feature.c and the calls in the main library are wrapped with USE_FEATURE guards.  I would like to add a target that will build the library like the LIB target but also include the feature.c file in the sources and define USE_FEATURE.

Comment: Does my answer below do what you want?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test yet, but it does look like what I want.  Once I verify that it works as I need, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key problem is that `<define>` is a free feature. And as such doesn't cause differentiation in the variant of what to build. To do what you want you need to create a new feature that describes what build option you are selecting (see [feature documentation](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/release/index.html#bbv2.extending.features)). For example:

```
import feature : feature ;
feature with-feat : no yes : optional propagated ;
```

You can then define whatever you want on your targets based on that feature's value. For example to define symbols or add sources:

```
lib LIB
    : [ glob *.c : feature.c ]
    : <link>static
      <use>/ProjectA//PUB
      <use>/ProjectB//PUB
      <with-feat>yes:<define>USE_FEATURE
      <with-feat>yes:<source>feature.c
    ;
```

Or you can use the `conditional` rule shorthand if you have many extra requirements to add:

```
lib LIB
    : [ glob *.c : feature.c ]
    : <link>static
      <use>/ProjectA//PUB
      <use>/ProjectB//PUB
      [ conditional <with-feat>yes :
        <define>USE_FEATURE
        <source>feature.c ]
    ;
```

To select a particular variation of that LIB from another target you specify the feature requirement in the target reference:

```
exe my-feat-exe : source.cpp LIB/<with-feat>yes ;
```