# Change lib's sources depending on conditional requirements in a factorized way using boost build/b2/bjam

Tags: conditional-statements, factorization, bjam, boost-build, b2

I have a lib target that needs different (additional) libraries on some OSes.

I would like to do something like:

```
lib MyLib : $(SOURCES) $(COMMON_LIBS) <target-os>windows:$(WINDOWS_LIBS) ;
```

but that returns `error: properties found in the 'sources' parameter for ./MyLib` I think it's because you cannot uses [conditional properties](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.reference.variants.propcond) there.

Or maybe using [alternatives](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.tutorial.conditions):

```
lib MyLib : $(SOURCES) $(COMMON_LIBS) ;

lib MyLib : $(SOURCES) $(COMMON_LIBS) $(WINDOWS_LIBS)
          : <target-os>windows
          ;
```

well that would works but with a lot of redundancy (and this example is not that complex) and I would like to factorize it.

How to factorize this ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28463499/how-do-you-conditionally-add-a-file-to-sources-in-boost-build

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [alias](https://www.bfgroup.xyz/b2/manual/main/index.html#bbv2.tasks.alias):

```
alias os_libs : $(WINDOWS_LIBS) : requirements <target-os>windows ;
alias os_libs : ; # no additional libs for other OSes

lib MyLib : $(SOURCES) $(COMMON_LIBS) os_libs ;
```